# Bootstrap button being clicked when it shouldn't be

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a minor problem; when I click on my textbox, it appears that the button to it's left is also being clicked.  I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1 using the default syntax.  How can I make it so when the textbox is clicked on, the button is not also clicked?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/6138/

And the code in question:

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
        <div class = "row">
          <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class = "btn btn-default no-outline" id = "customSearchButton" type = "button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id = "searchTextbox" placeholder="Search SRGs...">
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- .container-fluid -->
```

Comment: Try removing the `<label>` element wrapped around the input group. That seemed to fix the issue in my tests, and it looks like a fairly unnecessary element. I'd make this an answer, but I don't know the reason for why this behaviour is happening.. I'm quite curious on that part myself

Comment: Oh just saw this comment, sorry

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `<input group>` is wrapped inside a `<label>`.  When you click any part of the label the button goes to it's active state.  Like wrapping a checkbox inside a label.

Remove the `<label>` and it'll work.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/52VtD/6140/)

Answer (score 0):

just remove the button outside the label just like following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default no-outline" id="customSearchButton" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </span>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search SRGs...">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```